# Where can I find a free, simple VMWare VPN Appliance

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I'm wondering where I can find a free, simple VMWare VPN appliance (or VPN server I can run within windows). Something I can get up and running in 10 minutes, with minimal configuration. Needs to run on Windows 7 Home Premium (so using Windows VPN is not an option). Ideally would support clients in Mac and Windows.

I've been using this one: http://www.voipintouch.com/ovpn/index.html  -- but have found it to be a little unreliable.